# Tkinter - How to start my root window on a different monitor?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am learning Tkinter with `ttk` (python 2.7) and Win7.

I have 4 monitors on my computer, and I would like to open my project (root & root2 in example below) on other then my main monitor.

I am able to make 2 root windows OK, or more specifically, a root window, and a `Toplevel` window thus:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("My main window")
root2 = Toplevel(root)
root2.title("My debug window")
```

I tried `root.geometry('300x200-5+40')` but it seems I can only move it around the main screen.

Comment: Python and Tk don't know anything about how many monitors are connected to the computer, so you're left with experimenting with `root.geometry`, to my mind.

Comment: are you able to do this with other applications? like if you have two internet browsers open can you have one on one display and move the other to the second display?  I don't see why tkinter would work differently then other applications / windows.

Comment: I can open two Firefox windows, and move them to any monitor just fine AFTER I have created the windows. I can also open the two Python windows and move them to any monitor I like, but they always seem to START on my main screen. I guess will try to play with getting the positional status after I have moved them.

Comment: What platform? Windows, X Windows or MacOS? You have to ask the window manager to place the toplevel for you. That might mean finding the geometry of all the screens, or using the Extended Window Manager Hints on X Windows to select the desktop (see _NET_WM_DESKTOP)